# Add a "0" to the end of monetary values in the middle of a string of text

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet that has cells whose contents are a mix of text and dollar values. The entire cell is a string of text. For example, a cell may contain "Tom owes $65.5"

Now, unfortunately, I was given the spreadsheet with the dollar values not having the last "0" on them and since they are just strings of text, I cannot easily format the cells. I've tried using find and replace to change the values to the correct format, but I have thousands of records and it would take too long to try and account for all scenarios.

Is there a way to check if a part of the string is a dollar amount and then append the trailing 0 if need be? Something like

if $* is = 4 characters, append 0 to the end
if $* is < 3 characters, append .00 to the end

I should also say that the monetary values are not always at the end of the string of text and that they do not always end in just one decimal place. A "$6.75" can be found in the middle of a sentence. Also, just to throw another wrench in the gears, there can be other numbers in the string so I will need to be able to target only numbers following a dollar sign.

Comment: Is the dollar value always at the end of the cell's content?

Comment: @AndyG Good timing, I literally just updated my question with that and returned to see your comment. No, they are not always at the end unfortunately.

Comment: You should add a few more examples to your original post, to give a clearer idea.

Comment: Why don't you mark an answer as correct since either of them will work?

Comment: @DrydenLong haha good point. And you're exactly right about the impatience but very wrong about VBA. VBA is where I originally learned programming and I am several languages in by now. Just thought you wanted an answer that stuck to Excel formulas cuz I know the code can be a little overwhelming for beginners. By the way I gave your question that upvote and the favorite so lets not get too snippy up in here :)

Comment: @Lopsided My bad, I wasn't trying to be snippy. I began learning programming with Python and have recently been doing more in VBA. While I am far from proficient, I am also far from intimidated by the code. Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this VBA User-Defined Function (UDF) does what you want. It's based on my seminal work in http://yoursumbuddy.com/regex-function-sum-numbers-string/:

```
Function FixDollarsInStrings(Instring As String) As String

Dim regex As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim rgxMatch As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
Dim rgxMatches As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
Dim Outstring As String
Set regex = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
With regex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "(^| )\$(\d+|\.|,)+((?= )|$)"
    Outstring = Instring
    If .test(Instring) Then
        Set rgxMatches = .Execute(Instring)
        For Each rgxMatch In rgxMatches
            If IsNumeric(Trim(Replace(rgxMatch, ",", ""))) Then
                Outstring = Replace(Outstring, Trim(rgxMatch), Format(rgxMatch, "$#,##0.00"))
            End If
        Next rgxMatch
    End If
End With
FixDollarsInStrings = Outstring
End Function
```

To get it to work, you first need to set a reference to `Microsoft VbScript Regular Expressions 5.5` in Tools>References in the VBE.  Then copy this code to a regular module.

You then call it like:

=fixDollarsInStrings(A2)

[image]

Comment: +1 for a useful script. Unfortunately, I doubt he knows the first then about writing VBA User-Defined Functions :(

Comment: @Lopsided - Ah well, he's young and, besides, it's never too late :). Thanks for the vote.

Comment: This worked well, and seeing as I am fairly comfortable with regex, this will come in handy down the road if/when I need to modify the script for other scenarios. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Steps to do this in Excel . . .

I believe this can be done entirely in Excel without the use of VBA (although I can write you a small macro to do this if you show me a screen shot of your worksheet). Here is the basic outline of what we're going to do:

1. Insert a column (or use the one there if it is blank) to the right
   of the cells which contain the mixed data.
2. Insert a formula into each cell that (a) checks if the data has a dollar sign, (b) pulls the value starting at and to the right of
   the dollar sign, (c) converts that text into a value, and (d) inserts that value into the cell.
3. Insert another column to the right of the column we just created.
4. In that new column, insert a formula to concatenate the values from the first and second column. Make sure to use the text function to format the dollar amount when concatenating (I included it in the concatenation formula shown below).

---

### Illustrating the steps . . .

**Current Worksheet**

From what I imagining, here is a basic demonstration of how your
   worksheet looks now:

[image]

As you can see, the first (or *original* column) contains mixed text and dollar amounts.

**Insert the formula into the second column**

Next we insert this following formula into the second column:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("$",A4)>0,0)>0,VALUE(RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4)-SEARCH("$",A4))),"False")
```

[image: Picture of formula entered into second column]

**Insert the formula into the third column**

Now we insert the formula to concatenate the left side of the value from the first column, and the right side of the value from the second column (after formatting it again as text). Here is the formula:

```
=IF(B7<>"False",CONCATENATE(LEFT(A7,FIND("$",A7)-1),TEXT(B7,"$#,##0.00")),"")
```

[image: Picture of formula entered into third column]

Now you can just copy/paste the values back into the first column and you're done.

---

### Edit

I forgot to mention you should probably alter that concatenation formula to revert the value back to the original value if you are going to copy/paste them. Here's the edited formula:

```
=IF(B7<>"False",CONCATENATE(LEFT(A7,FIND("$",A7)-1),TEXT(B7,"$#,##0.00")),A7)
```

Comment: I liked that this could be done as just a formula rather than a script, but since Doug's answer was easier for me to modify for future issues I chose his. +1 for doing this outside of VBA though! Thanks!

Comment: @DrydenLong no worries glad you got it worked out. Thanks for the upvote